# How to fetch running jobs from commvault based on mediaagent using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Kindly let me know that how i can fetch the running jobs from commvault which are running on the specific media agent server using powershell. I need to pass the media agent server name for fetching the running jobs from that specific.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question would be better asked in serverfault.com. If your question is more around your PowerShell code, please provide examples of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

& adding from woter324's answer, you should let us know what you've tried (if so), and what's going on. Documentation available at https://documentation.commvault.com/11.24/essential/48984_storage_resource_operations.html